# How to use a class as a data set in RDLC report?

Tags: model-view-controller, rdlc

I am new in this field. I am currently working on Report Viewer 11.0 with MVC5.

Here is my `Employee.cs` class:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I want to use this class as a data set in my RDLC report.

What to do for this ?

Comment: Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695864/using-net-class-as-the-datasource-with-ssrs-rdlc