# Microsoft Report does not work in VS2013 and MVC/Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-reporting

I am using VS2013 and I am creating a really simple application in MVC.
I have to create a report, so I thought to use the reports included in VS2013.
I would like to use the classes of my model to create the report. But for a strange I do not see those classes. 
At the start I could attach my report just to the database, so I looked for a solution on internet. I have found this:

[Can't see or add Website Data Sources in RDLC report in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923569/cant-see-or-add-website-data-sources-in-rdlc-report-in-asp-net-mvc)

Unfortunatelly, this do not solve my problem... Now, I can see some namespaces in choosing the datasource, but I do not see my Model. 
Following a class of my model:

```
namespace Export.Microsoft.Reports.Models
{
    public class OrderModel
    {
        public Company Sender { get; set; }
        public Company Receiver { get; set; }
        public Company Other { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

And following is what I see when I try to select a class of my model:

[image]

How can I solve? Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, In my model I need to write some code to retrieve data.

For example:

```
namespace Export.Microsoft.Reports.Models
{
    public class OrderModel
    {
        public Company Sender { get; set; }
        public Company Receiver { get; set; }
        public Company Other { get; set; }
        ...

        public OrderModel GetAllOrders()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Only in this way, the model appear in the list and I can select it.